# Vue.js pretty-checkbox-vue install and get it to run

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am a complete beginner in JavaScript and Vue.js. I started a Vue.js project with vue-cli yesterday, because I need it for my job and I ran into some problems. I wanted to install "pretty-checkbox-vue" and it is currently in my 'node_module' folder. 
In the README.md of the [Gitrepo](https://github.com/hamed-ehtesham/pretty-checkbox-vue#browser) for this package it says  :

**Browser**
Include the script file, then install the component with Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox); e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/pretty-checkbox-vue/dist/pretty-checkbox-vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);
</script>
```

**Module**

```
import PrettyCheckbox from 'pretty-checkbox-vue';
Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);
```

The questions are :
**Where do I put these code snippets in ?** \

I have a main.js and App.vue.
And if I write `import PrettyCheckbox from 'pretty-checkbox-vue';` in my main.js I get a "could not find a declaration file for module 'pretty-check-box'" message.

**Is this message normal, becaus I haven't included the script file ?**

Thank you in advance!

EDIT :

**main.js :**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
    
import PrettyCheckbox from 'pretty-checkbox-vue';

Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Folder Structure**

- Project_folder

  - node_modules

    - pretty-checkbox
    - pretty-checkbox-vue
  - src

    - main.js
    - App.vue
  - public

    - index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use that component globally inside your app, and you're a beginner, I'd recommend you install it as a module. First, run `npm i --save-dev pretty-checkbox-vue` in your project folder. Make sure you've installed the package on your project directory, so `pretty-checkbox-vue` is actually on `node_modules` folder of your specific project with all other project dependencies, not just a random folder elsewhere.

Then just paste this code

```
import PrettyCheckbox from 'pretty-checkbox-vue';

Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);
```

in `main.js`

Make sure all your imports are there before the rest of your code starts.

After the installation, just follow the instructions and use that component in any template throughout the project.

If you're getting errors while in development mode, try `npm install` on your project and `npm run serve` again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already installed it and it is in my current project folder in node_modules. However, if I paste the code you suggested in the main.js then in the `import PrettyCheckbox from 'pretty-checkbox-vue' ` I get 3 grey dots under 'pretty ...' and once I hover over the points i get the message described in the beginning

Comment: Can you provide your main.js file, and maybe your Project folder structure? I think I can help better that way.

Also, do you need this component globally? If not, maybe you can only import it in pages you will need. 

You can also just add the "Browser" inside your public folder -> index.html, paste it at the end of your <body> content, instead of module imports.